# Kendo UI Grid, get column Index or Name from DataItem

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an editor function, where I receive a dataItem parameter. I'm wondering if there's a way to retrieve the column name or index from this dataItem.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/radio-buttons-custom-editor

Comment: Use a debugger or console.log(dataItem) to see what properties it has. It will have an id which indicates the row index. Please expand your question to include code for your specific case if you need a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the template is used for all rows and for column CategoryId. So that method will be called with each dataItem (actually a data item / row).

You already know the column (it's CategoryID or index 1 - starting from 0). To get the row index you can just find it by uid:

```
 var row = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid")
              .tbody
              .find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']");
                
  console.log(row.index());
```

I think you have a misconception about how that template works and you are looking for something like on change event where you capture the cell/row/column.

Quoting:

```
 change: function (e) {
          var $grid = e.sender; // grid ref
          var $cell = $grid.select(); // selected td
          var $row = $cell.closest('tr'); //selected tr
          var row_uid = $row.attr('data-uid'); //uid of selected row
          var cell_index = $cell.index(); //cell index 0 based
          var row_index = $row.index(); //row index 0 based
          var row_data = $grid.dataItem($row).toJSON(); //selected row data

          console.log(row_data);
      },
```